# lenght of a list of elementtree turn 0 after second call

Tags: python, list, elementtree

I have a code like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.fromstring("<all_products><product instrument_name='nice_instrument'></product></all_products>")
product_iter = tree.iterfind("product[@instrument_name='nice_instrument']")
len(list(product_iter))
```

And this gives me len of the list of product_iter 1 as expected.

But if a call the len(list(product_iter)) again I get 0.

I dont understand why this happens. Can someone explain why the product_iter variable is somehow changed whan a call the len to the list?

Looking at the documentation for elementtree https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html I dont see any information how to explain this.

Regards
Trygve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product_iter` is an iterator, not a list. If you convert it to a list, the `len` will stay `1`:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> tree = etree.fromstring("<all_products><product instrument_name='nice_instrument'></product></all_products>")
>>> product_iter = tree.iterfind("product[@instrument_name='nice_instrument']")
>>> products = list(product_iter)
>>> len(products)
1
>>> len(products)
1
```

Comment: ah, ok. I understand. But the command list(product_iter) convert the iterator to a list. Is it possible to do this without modifying the iterator?

Comment: Once an iterator is consumed, there is no way to reset it. You could ask the tree again with `tree.iterfind('....`, or use `tree.findall()` instead.

Comment: a list() will consume your iterator, save the list if you want to use it more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line here I think is to understand iterators in python.

Maybe findall instead of iterfind is better in this case.